# Transport package in Success folder

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

In `cd_deployer_conf` file we have set `Cleanup="false`, so that transport package will not be deleted after publishing, but we can see 3 different packages for single publish actions like

`tcm_0-264891-66560.COMMIT`

`tcm_0-264891-66560.Content`

`tcm_0-264891-66560.PREPARE`

Is this the normal behavior?  Or we can do some configuration so that only one (.content) package will be created?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is indeed normal behavior.

Deployment in Tridion 2011 is transactional, so you're seeing the different phases of the transaction there.

If you publish to multiple targets, you will see all of them get and process their `PREPARE` and `Content` packages. Only after all of the targets report success on processing those packages, will they receive the `Commit` package.